# Card game script randomly stops in the middle of a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote this recursive function that plays the card game war and returns the number of turn in total and when i try to execute it with a for loop it randomly stops
i tried to run it with a while loop from cmd directly and using different shuffling methods
when it run there are no error and it just stops

```
import random
import sys
print(sys.setrecursionlimit(5000))

def what(l1, l2, index,count):
    count += 1
    if not l1 or not l2:
        return count
    if l1[index] > l2[index]:
        l3 = l2[0:index+1]+l1[0:index+1]
        random.shuffle(l3)
        l1 = l1[index+1:]+l3
        l2 = l2[index+1:]
        return what(l1,l2,0,count)
    if l2[index] > l1[index]:
        l3 = l2[0:index+1]+l1[0:index+1]
        random.shuffle(l3)
        l2 = l2[index+1:]+l3
        l1 = l1[index+1:]
        return what(l1,l2,0,count)
    if l1[index] == l2[index]:
        if len(l1)>index+3 and len(l2)>index+3:
            return what(l1, l2, index + 3,count)
        else:
            return count

array = [0]*5000
for item in range(1000):
    CardDeck = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13]
    random.shuffle(CardDeck)
    result = what(CardDeck[0:27], CardDeck[27:54], 0,0)
    array[result] += 1
    print(str(item) + ':' + str(result))
print(array)
```

the program should print an array with all the times a game was played with the same amount of truns

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Every time I run the script it prints 1000 results, and `sum(array)` is 1000.

Comment: You're setting the recursion limit to *5 times* its default value - it's unlikely that there's enough stack space to support that, I would expect a hard crash from this code.  Fortunately, all of your recursion is in the form of *tail calls*, so it's fairly easy to convert the function to a non-recursive form.  Just wrap a `while True:` loop around the body of the function, and instead of `return what(...)`, just reassign the function parameters and let another loop iteration handle it.